# XSLT extensions: I am trying to use a custom java function in XSLT but am not able to pin point the mistake

Tags: java, xslt

I am trying to use a factorial function from a java class. The other two functions that I have used are working fine but I don't know what I am doing wrong with the factorial function.

Below is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:date="java.util.Date" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="function-available('date:toString') and function-available('date:new')">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="date:toString(date:new())"/></p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if xmlns:string="java.lang.String" test="function-available('string:toUpperCase')" exclude-result-prefixes="string">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="string:toUpperCase('pune')" /></p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if xmlns:fact="java" test="function-available('fact:factorial.calculateFactorial')" exclude-result-prefixes="fact">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="fact:factorial.calculateFactorial(5)" /></p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the java class:

```
public class factorial{
public int calculateFactorial(int number){
    int fact=1;
    while(number>=1){
        fact = fact * number;
        number--;
    }
    return fact;
}
}
```

The class and the xslt are in the same folder.

The error is:

```
Error at xsl:value-of on line 13 column 59 of extension-functions.xslt:
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 26 on line 13 in {fact:calculateFactorial(5)}:
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {urn:java:factorial}calculateFactorial()
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

Saxon version is: Saxon 9.1.0.8J from Saxonica

Comment: Use the `-t` command line option to see the version and other information like class loading.

Comment: What is the error reported?

Comment: @MartinHonnen : Added the version as well, thanks!

Comment: Try putting your Java class in a package and adjust accordingly (and name it Factorial).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:

    Error at xsl:value-of on line 13 column 59 of extension-functions.xslt:
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 26 on line 13 in {fact:calculateFactorial(5)}:
    Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java:com.facto.Factorial}calculateFactorial()
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

Comment: Two suggestions: (a) use the -TJ option for better diagnostics when extension functions can't be found; (b) since your factorial code doesn't use any fields, make it a static method. Non-static methods need to supply an extra argument (an instance of the class).

Comment: @MichaelKay : Doesn't work when I make my method static. Same error. I think I am using Saxon9HE. Does it supports this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

With Saxon 9.6 PE the following works for me:

```
<xsl:if xmlns:fact="java:Factorial" test="function-available('fact:new') and function-available('fact:calculateFactorial')" exclude-result-prefixes="fact">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="fact:calculateFactorial(fact:new(), 5)" /></p>
</xsl:if>
```

Java class is

```
public class Factorial{
public int calculateFactorial(int number){
    int fact=1;
    while(number>=1){
        fact = fact * number;
        number--;
    }
    return fact;
}
}
```

command line to call Saxon is

```
java.exe -cp 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Saxonica\SaxonPE9.6J\saxon9pe.jar;.' net.sf.saxon.Transform .\test2015010101.xml .\test2015010601.xsl
```

where `.` contains `Factorial.class`.

Comment: Tried! This is what I got:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/Transform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.Transform

Comment: Well, did you adapt the `cp` class path to your installation of Saxon? I don't know where you have it installed on your machine.

Comment: I haven't installed it. I am just using the jar file via command line. Is it something to do with the edition of saxon?

Comment: Well whether you have installed it or not, somewhere in a directory on your machine you do have a `jar` and obviously the `-cp 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Saxonica\SaxonPE9.6J\saxon9pe.jar;.'` needs to be adopted to reflect the location and name of the jar on your machine.

Comment: I did that. I put the absolute path of the directory where the jar is kept, which in this case is the same as the directory of my xslt. I do not have the EE or PE of saxon. It is a free edition, home edition I think.

Comment: Here is the command line:

java -cp 'C:\MyFolder\XSLT_Training\extending-xslt\saxon9.jar;Factorial.class' net.sf.saxon.Transform zoo.xml extension-functions.xslt

Comment: I am not sure the Java class path allows putting `class` files in it, as far as I remember it takes directories and jars. First try to establish that you can run Saxon without doing any extension stuff, once you have that I don't see why my suggestions should not work as the class name to be called has not changed between Saxon 9.1 and 9.6.

Comment: Also note that my command line is an example working in the Powershell on Windows, for a normal command prompt on Windows I think you need double quotes around the class path e.g. `java.exe -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Saxonica\SaxonPE9.6J\saxon9pe.jar;." net.sf.saxon.Transform test2015010101.xml test2015010601.xsl`.

Comment: If I exclude the last `xsl:if`(the factorial stuff), the xslt is working as expected. I also put the double quotes and also tried without the class file in the command line. Doesn't work :(

Comment: This is how:

java -jar saxon9.jar -s:zoo.xml -xsl:extension-functions.xslt -o:output.xml

Comment: Then try to run a simple stylesheet using the `-cp` option instead of the `-jar` option with `java -cp "saxon.jar;." net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:output.xml` (in the Windows command prompt window) or `java -cp 'saxon.jar;.' net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:output.xml`, simply to establish that you can run Saxon 9.1 that way with the class path being set.